# The height of a prime ideal in the $\kappa[[X]][Y]$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $\kappa$ be a field and $S=\kappa[[X]]$ be the ring of power series which depends on the indeterminate $X$. Now consider the ring $S[Y]$, the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $S$ and indeterminate $Y$.

$\Bbb{Q}$usetion: How can we could prove that the ideal $(XY-1)$ in $S[Y]$ is a prime ideal of height 1?

Comment: It might be easier solve the problem by replacing $\kappa[[X]]$ by a discrete valuation ring and $X$ by a uniformizing element.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring. Then $A_\pi$ is a field where $\pi$ is a uniformizing parameter; this follows immediately from the fact that every element in a DVR is unit times a non-negative power of the uniformizing parameter.

Thus $A[Y]/(\pi Y - 1)$ is a field and so $\pi Y - 1$ is maximal.